# Setting up CentOS firewall for remote MongoVUE GUI access

Tags: mongodb, ssh, centos, mongovue

I'm trying to set-up MongoVUE to connect to a networked server running MongoDB. I can connect to it very easily either via SSHing in Putty or using mongo ip:port in windows command line.

However, when setting up a connection via MongoVUE's SSH tunnel, I get the error:

```
Unable to connect to server 127.0.0.1:5252: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:5252.
```

So I assume there's something wrong with the firewall configuration.

However, my /etc/sysconfig/iptables contains the line:

```
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 27017 -j ACCEPT
```

What else should be in place to let this connect?

Here is the MongoVue SSH configuration:

[image]

Comment: I'm confused as `127.0.0.1` is your local host not a remote system.  The unable to connect is saying that you are trying to connect to MongoDB on your local system.

Comment: MongoVUE allows for an SSH tunnel though, which is setup

Comment: The error means that nothing is listening on your local machine on TCP port 5252.  Is there any configuration for the SSH tunnel that we can look at?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/96tAh.jpg is the configuration. I don't know why its going for 5252 :/

Comment: What happen's when you click on the `Test` button?  Same error?  What system has the `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` file as MongoVUE appears to be a Windows-only application?  What TCP port is your MongoDB listening on?

Comment: I get this blank error: http://puu.sh/1aKAD when trying to test the connection. Then when I connect I get the above error. 
Yes, MongoVUE is a windows application. I am remotely ssh-ing to another mongo-db machine. Mongod on the remote machine says it is running on 27017

Answer (score 5):

I get the same error using the built-in SSH feature of MongoVUE.

I suspect that this is a bug in MongoVUE.  I was able to get SSH to work using Putty following the instructions at http://www.mongovue.com/2011/08/04/mongovue-connection-to-remote-server-over-ssh/.

[image]

[image]

Below is Putty Tunnel configuration: Putty configured to listen on 5151 and then connect to 27017 on remote system (MongoD).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had to use a little trick to make built-in "SSH Tunnel" work.

It turns out that default IP for a `localhost` in Windows 7 is Ipv6 address, so you have to add (or just un-comment) the following line into your *\System32\drivers\etc\hosts* file

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

And configure Mongovue connection as follows (with your IP for sure):

- Settings: [image: Settings]
- SSH Tunnel: [image: SSH Tunnel]

Notice the same IP on both tabs